# DataMapper Associations

Tags: ruby, associations, datamapper

I was just trying to create a database with DataMapper. I am trying to associate the class User with class Post, Post2, Post3 and Post4. And I didnt get any message or changes in the Data SQLite Free, a database Mac application that I am using. Below is the code I created. Did I make any mistakes? Thanks!

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'


DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/wiki2.db")   

class User
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :username, Text, :required => true
    property :password, Text, :required => true
    property :date_joined, DateTime
    property :edit, Boolean, :required => true, :default => false   

    has n, :posts
    has n, :post2s
    has n, :post3s
    has n, :post4s
end

class Post
    include DataMapper::Resource 
    property :id, Serial
    property :content, Text
    property :created_at, DateTime     
    property :updated_at, DateTime 

    belongs_to :user
end

class Post2
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :content, Text
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime

    belongs_to :user

end

class Post3
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :content, Text
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime

    belongs_to :user

end

class Post4
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :content, Text
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime

    belongs_to :user

end


DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're actually asking.

Comment: Do you have any sources to provide more info on Data SQLite Free app you are using on Mac ?

Comment: The code works fine. It must be a problem on the side of the application you are using.